# How to convert datepicker MUI reactjs to arabic

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change language in datepicker MUI to Arabic but nothing works with me. I'm using '@mui/x-date-pickers'

Using locale or localetext in LocalizationProvider hits error.
Using theme Doesn't hit error but is not working too

Answer (score 1):

According to MUI react-date-pickers localization, it doesn't support Arabic language. [Check the documentation.](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/localization/)

Despite that, you can achieve the result using `date-fns`.

Check the code sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-keldysh-dzwgkd?file=/src/App.js